# Submodular functions: reference request

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms, optimization

I would be very much interested in references to the theory of submodular functions (from basics to advanced).

In particular, I am studying approximations to hard optimization problems and I want to develop my foundations in submodular functions as they are relevant to the optimization problems I have been studying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shameless self-promotion: [Greedy Δ-Approximation Algorithm for Covering with Arbitrary Constraints and Submodular Cost](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~neal/publications?paper=Koufogiannakis12Greedy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

References such as the ones suggested by Standa Zivny are of course very good. Let me add to the list the new book by Andras Frank titled "Connections in Combinatorial Optimization" published by Oxford University Press, 2011. All of these references treat submodular functions from a classical combinatorial optimization point of view where submodularity primarily appears in constraints. There have been several recent applications and developments with submodular objective functions for which one needs a slightly different view point. There are many papers to give a list here. I would however recommend Shaddin Dughmi's survey on continuous extensions of submodular functions http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0322v3.

Comment: Thank you for the survey, it looks very good! I've recently purchased Frank's book, but haven't managet to read it yet so I was a bit reluctant to recommend it.

Comment: @Chandra, time for you to write a survey on the most recent stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for the survey link. I was looking for something similar to this.

Answer (score 9):

The references I use (and like) are selected chapters in Schrijver's 3-volume Combinatorial Optimization: Polyhedra and Efficiency (Springer) and Vygen's Combinatorial Optimization (Springer). There is a book devoted to submodular functions by Fujishige: Submodular Functions and Optimization, volume 58 of Annals of Discrete Mathematics, North-Holland (2nd edition from 2005).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add "[Submodular Functions and Electrical Networks](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~hn/book/SubmodularFunction_2ed.pdf)" by [H. Narayanan](http://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~hn/).

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. There are notes on matroids as well on his homepage.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorites, [Jan vondrak's thesis](http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/data/KAM_thesis.pdf) and many of his papers.

Answer (score 0):

Two more publications
1. Goldengorin, B., Ghosh, D.: A multilevel search algorithm for the maximization of submodular functions applied to the quadratic cost partition problem. J. Glob. Optim. 32, 65–82 (2005)

2. B. Goldengorin. Maximization of submodular functions: Theory and enumeration algorithms. European Journal of Operational Research, 198(1):102–112, 2009